# Laravel 5.4 multiple dropdown on belongstomany over two pivots

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, dropdown, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to connect companies that are used by specific user role. A user with a specific role can "work" for multiple companies. A company can "employ" multiple users. I have 5 tables (users, role_user, roles, companies and company_user)

Models relations:

```
App\User:

public function roles()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\Role')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }


    public function companies()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\Company')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }


App\Role:
    public function users()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\User')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }


App\Companies:
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');  // with user_role ??
    }
```

Companies Controller

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id) {

$company = Company::findOrFail($id);

$users = User::where('role_id',4)->pluck('username')->all(); // no role_id column
$users = User::pluck('username','id')->all();  // returns all users

return view('companies.edit', compact(['company','users']));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    /* TODO */
}
```

Edit view

```
{!! Form::select('users[]', $users, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) !!}
```

I want to asign users whith a specific user role to these companies. Is there a way to setup the relation or perhaps a scope?

Bonus question :) Is there a simple way to display concatinated value in a dropdown? First name + Last name instead of username?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the tidiest solution but it seems to work :)

Model

```
public function scopeOfRole($query, $role) {
    return $query->
    join('role_user', 'role_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->
    join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'role_user.role_id')->
    select(
        DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(users.first_name," ",users.last_name) as username'),
            'users.id')->
    where('roles.name', $role)->
    groupBy('users.id');
}
```

Controler

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id) {

$company = Company::findOrFail($id);
$users = User::OfRole('my role')->pluck('username','users.id')->all();

return view('companies.edit', compact(['company','users']));
}
```

edit view

```
{!! Form::select('users[]', $users, $company->users()->pluck('users.id'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'multiple' => 'multiple']) !!}
```